# Trouble looping through a data file and storing integers in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, integer

I am having a problem with a loop. I am writing a program that loops through lottery drawings and does some different analysis' on the drawings. The problem I am having is since a loop is 0-based but there is no number 0 in lottery drawings I cant figure out how to start the loop at 1 instead of 0. Also, when I cut out an integer, if the integer is a single digit the loop doesn't see the zero before the single digit and counts all of the 0-9 in all of the integers. I am trying to grab an integer and then tick that element of the array. Here is the loop.

```
    'Choices(59) is passed into the loop from a click event
     Private Sub GetFrequency(Choices() As Integer)
     Dim Size As Integer = UsersChosenHistory.Length() 'Size
     Dim Number As Integer = 1
     Dim Start As Integer = 0
     Dim Finish As Integer = 3'Grab 3 chars, a space + 2 digit Integer

  For i As Integer = 1 To Size - 1 Step 1
     Number.ToString("d2")'I've also tried Number.ToString("D2") (Capitol D)
     Number = UsersChosenHistory.Substring(Start, Finish) 'Grab an integer
     Choices(Number) += "1"    'Store it in the corresponding array element
     Start += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

When running through the loop with the F11 key the single digits do not show the leading "0" even though the data file does include the "0", and as I mentioned above the array shows a "0" as the first digit in the frequence grid. I'm really confused with this loop, any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm just learning VB.Net and this has me stumped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: numbers/integers do not have leading zeroes.  the data in the file is text.  when you read the file you could leave element(0) empty and just loop thru the rest.  `Number.ToString("d2")` doesnt do anything because there is nothing "catching" the result, `Choices(Number) += "1" ` is trying to add a numeral to a number.  Turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: .Net arrays start at 0.  Turn Option Strict On and fix those errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Size - 1 Step 1
     Number = int.Parse(UsersChosenHistory.Substring(i*3,3).Replace(" ","")) 
     Choices(Number) += "1"    
     Next
```

*For the "0" issue, ignore it. Choices(0) will never be incremented.*